# Capture Nginx_status to zabbix (v3 or above)

Tags: nginx, zabbix, zabbix-agent

i want to know if there is a template for capturing nginx_status to zabbix. recently searched for hours but their template just work for earlier version. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

An excellent place to find Zabbix templates is https://share.zabbix.com/ . There's an nginx template for Zabbix 3.2 [here](https://share.zabbix.com/cat-app/web-servers/nginx-for-zabbix-3-2)

Comment: sorry for a long respon :) yes there is 3.2 . i've tried but error : unsupported tag zabbix_version . currently using cacti for a while . still better zabbix on GUI . thanks for the answer